# Including AdMobs Ads in a listView

Tags: java, android, admob

Id like to include AdMobs ads in my app, but Im not sure how to add them.

My main activity calls setContentView on my main.xml, but my main.xml consists of only one ListView

```
<ListView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/listView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
  />
```

Adding the adview to the layout,

```
<ListView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.t3hh4xx0r.romcrawler"
  android:id="@+id/listView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" >

  <com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" 
    myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF" 
    myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC" />
  </ListView>
```

of course causes a force close on launch, as listViews aren't allowed to have child layouts.

Whats the best way to get around this? Creating the ad view in java? And if so, could you provide some example code of how I would create it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a layout like this: This way the ad will show at the bottom. By setting the weightSum to 1 and then saying the weight of the listview is 1 it will take all space that is left after creating the ad.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#E4E9F5"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="your_adunitid_here"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Got me on the right track, but i still have no ads actually being displayed. In logcat I see its receiving the ad url, but not the ad itself. `I/Ads     ( 1432): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)` What would be causing that?

Comment: Ok, did you fill in the adUnitId and include the INTERNET permission in your manifest?

Comment: even after my device was set as a test device, i still receive the same message.
`AdRequest ar = new AdRequest();
        ar.addTestDevice("4B605421C6EAA120E18B7FA165D2E980");`

Comment: adUnitID is the 'Publisher ID' given by AdMob. You can find this when you look at your app(s) in AdMob and click on Manage Settings.

Comment: also the internet permission?

Comment: And according to adMobs, they never received a request from my app yet. perhaps I just havent waited lng enough for it to activate?

Comment: yes, internet permissions have been there for a while. needed for the app functions. and the network state permission required by admob

Comment: ah! there there are. I guess it just needed more time. Thank you for your help!